# Product attributes per category

Tags: php, mysql

I have a category table with category id, name and parent. I have a products table with a link to the category table named  `cat_id`.

Now I have diffrent kind of products and not every product has the same kind of attributes like colour or  pieces. So my problem is: How to setup that I can have different attributes per category?

I am stuck at how I can best link this.
Now I have a column in the products table with all the attributes, but also the ones that are not used per category.

Comment: you can have one more table for attribute storage.

Comment: Look for `Entity Attribute Value` ('EAV') modeling

Comment: ...and then avoid it like the plague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make an attribute category table:

`attcat_id` `attcat_name`

Make an attribute table:

`att_id` `attcat_id`(foreign key) `att_name`

This way these two will be linked

Now in category table associate each category with attribute category

`cat_id` `cat_name` `attcat_id`(foreign key)

So idea is to group attributes as per attribute category and link attribute category to Product Category. For example, an attribute category `mobile` will have attributes as `price` `screensize` `camera` `flashlight`.

Now link `mobile` i.e. attribute category to your product category `Mobiles`.